# ms-access: designing a report: printing text on specific x,y coordinates

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i need to design a report that will print text on specified x,y coordinates

for example, i will input (50,50), (60,60), (70,70) and i will have my program print text at those specific coordinates on the report. in total there will be about 50 different coordinates.

how do i achieve this? should i be using a label control or a textbox? should i be creating the controls dynamically or should i already have controls set at the specified regions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ms-access: filling out an application by printing over it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885466/ms-access-filling-out-an-application-by-printing-over-it)

Comment: Please explain exactly why you think you NEED to do this. Either you're using the wrong program (i.e., what you need to do is not suitable to an Access report) or you don't really need it in the first place. You've defined your solution, which you don't know how to implement, but you haven't described the problem it's designed to solve. You likely have chosen the wrong solution to the problem.

Comment: hi david, can i get your email, i would love to get your feedback

Comment: No, you can't have my email. If you have real questions, ask them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is done when creating some type of Wizard for Access and not during the usage of a production application. You can use CreateControl but the form has to be opened in design mode first. This probably doesn't match your version of Access and may need to be adjusted.
[How to Use the CreateControl() and CreateReportControl() Functions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210595)

This is what it was like in the days of pre-printed forms (sometimes in triplicate) and dot matrix printers. I suggest you take a management role, and suggest they scrap the paper forms, buy a laser printer and make this task about a hundred times easier.

Comment: You really don't want to add controls at runtime, because even if you don't save them, it increments the counter of the number of controls added to a form/report, and there's a lifetime limit of 700-odd controls. Likewise, you can't make design changes like this in an MDE/ACCDE, so it's a non-starter in the preferred production environment, anyway.

Comment: Additionally, even if you make it work, if you've got cert for signed code for your app, changes like this will invalidate the cert! That's 3 good reasons not to do it.